# Why HTTP is far more used than HTTPS?

Tags: http, https

I hope every reason is mentioned, I think that performance is the main reason, but I hope every one to mention what he\she knows about this.

It's more recommended that you explain every thing, I'm still a starter.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: HTTS is encrypted, so by nature slower.  The question should by why would anyone ever use HTTPS?  ...and the answer is security.   So it's basically a security/performance tradeoff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It makes pages load slower, at least historically. Nowadays this may not be so relevant.
- It's more complex for the server admin to setup and maintain, and perhaps too difficult for the non-professional.
- It's costly for small sites to get and regularly renew a valid SSL certificate from the SSL certificate authorities.
- It's unnecessary for most of your web browsing.
- It disables the HTTP_REFERER field, so sites can't tell where you've come from. Good for privacy, bad for web statistics analysis, advertisers and marketing.
- Edit: forget that you also need a separate IP address for each domain using SSL. This is [incompatible with name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html), which is widely used for cheap shared web hosting. This might become a non-issue if/when IPv6 takes off, but it makes it impossible for every domain to have SSL using IPv4.

Answer (score 6):

HTTPS is more expensive than plain HTTP:

- Certificates issued by trusted issuer are not free
- TLS/SSL handshake costs time
- TLS/SSL encryption and compression takes time and additional resources (the same for decryption and decompression)

But I guess the first point is the main reason.

Comment: And it's not even really secure aganist a man-in-the-middle attacker

Answer (score 2):

Essentially it's as Gumbo posts. But given the advances in power of modern hardware, there's an argument that [there's no reason to not use HTTPS any more](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html).

The biggest barrier is the trusted certificate. You can go self-signed, but that then means all visitors to your site get an "unrested certificate" warning. The traffic *will* still be encrypted, and it is no less secure, but big certificate warnings can put potential visitors off.

Comment: Unless your visitors can recognize your certificate, it is less secure due to the possibility of man-in-the-middle attacks. Anyone on the path between your visitor and your server can install a proxy server that exhibits the same behaviour - users need to accept the certificate, only this time it's not your server's certificate, but their own.

Comment: Just google "free ssl certificate", and use the first result(StartSSL). I am happily using it for several years and it is trusted in all major browsers (except only IE6) so that man-in-the-middle attacks are mitigated. The certificate is valid for full one year and then it can be created again. For small sites this is fully sufficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

I maybe stating the obvious, but not all [content](http://failblog.org) needs transport layer security.